# Class __str__ magic-methods

Tags: python, class, magic-methods

Hi I am learning classes and special methods and I having trouble with the code below, as I cant seem to figure out how to get the def __ str__ to work, it prints none

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.radius = radius
        print(f'Circle of radius {radius}')
    def circumference (self):
        self.circumference=round(2*3.14*self.radius,2)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"the circumference is: {self.circumference}"

circle_1=Circle(5)
print(circle_1.circumference())
```

Comment: You don't use the `str` representation of your `Circle` object anywhere. You print the result of calling `circle_1.circumference()`, but that method always returns `None`.

Comment: Thanks for that, however, I do need to use __str __ to print circumference, any help or hints?

Comment: `__str__` is used whenever you need *the string representation of an object*, e.g. if you `print(circle_1)`, or by calling `str` on the object, e.g. `circle_string = str(circle_1)`. Note, you've named your method the same as an attribute, which will cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
class Circle:
    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.radius = radius
        print(f'Circle of radius {radius}')
    
    def circumference (self):
        return round(2*3.14*self.radius,2)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "the circumference is: {}".format(self.circumference())
     
circle_1=Circle(5) 
print(circle_1)
```

You should try this.